# Getting errors with sending data to the external API (Laravel)

Tags: php, validation, laravel-9

I'm getting errors with sending data to the external API (Laravel). I don't understand what the problem is. Everything seems to be correct. But, unfortunately, I didn't find the correct answer on other sites on the web.

**This is my send method**

```
public function checkFile(Request $request)
{
    $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'
    ])
        ->attach('CodeFile', $request->file('CodeFile'))
        ->withBasicAuth($this->login, $this->password)
        ->post($this->base_url.'/api/Checker/CheckFile', [
            'CodeFile' => $request->file('CodeFile'),
            'LanguageType' => $request->LanguageType,
            'ProblemShortCode' => $request->ProblemShortCode
        ]);

    return $response;
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-ab5d61bff21331449b27984d982a0e21-78eba0448be1c342-00",
  "errors": {
    "": [
      "Failed to read the request form. Missing content-type boundary."
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'
```

Header.

Sometimes is set automatically by uploader.

Let me know

Comment: I tried but it didn't help. If I remove this header, the method does not take CodeFile